# Python how to get rid of a nested list

Tags: python, list

Good evening,

I have a python variable like so

```
myList = ["['Ben'", " 'Dillon'", " 'Rawr'", " 'Mega'", " 'Tote'", " 'Case']"]
```

I would like it to look like this instead

```
myList = ['Ben', 'Dillon', 'Rawr', 'Mega', 'Tote', 'Case']
```

If I do something like this

```
','.join(myList)
```

It gives me what I want but the type is a String

I also would like it to keep the type of List. I have tried using the Join method and split method. And I have been debugging use the `type()` method. It tells me that the type in the original scenario is a list.

I appreciate any and all help on this.

Comment: Where is that strange list coming from? Can you fix it to produce proper JSON so you don't have to do this?

Comment: @Barmar When I send data through postman to my Python backend, It gets transformed to that becomes it comes in as an list already. Our frontend sends the data as a string so we dont have the issue. Definitely something to look into more

Comment: Either there's a problem with how you're parsing it in the Python backend, or you're formatting it incorrectly in postman.

Comment: I am thinking It is with Postman because when I send it from the frontend It works fine. I will look into it more If it becomes an issue, and ask another question If I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the inner list elements, then call `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it as a list of strings.

```
import ast

myList = ast.literal_eval(",".join(myList))
```

Comment: Probably want to join on comma, not empty string

Answer (score 0):

Also can be done by truncating Strings, therefore avoiding the import of ast.

```py
myList[5] = (myList[5])[:-1]
for n in range(0, len(myList)):
    myList[n] = (myList[n])[2:-1]
```